# Word for Mac 2011 cannot do Thai word breaking

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word

I'm using Word for Mac 2011 to write a Thai document.  It doesn't know how to do Thai word breaking.  The previous version (e.g., Office 2003, 2007 for Windows) can do the word breaking.

How can I fix this?⠀⠀⠀⠀